# How to find the index of array in custom array list ...?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I want tofind the index of the custom array list.
This is my custom array list:

```
private ArrayList<UserData> ListItems = new ArrayList<>();

UserData list = new UserData("list", "5", R.drawable.email_black, false);

UserData list1 = new UserData("list1", "3",R.drawable.text_msg, false);

UserData list2 = new UserData("list2", "2",R.drawable.phone_call, false);

ListItems.add(list);
ListItems.add(list1);
ListItems.add(list2);
```

I am doing like below but not getting the index .

```
int m = ListItems.indexOf("list1");

UserData obj = ListItems.get(m);
String name = obj.getName();
```

I need list1 in name string.

Comment: You will have to pass the `userData` object in `listItems.indexOf()` not the string in order to get the index.

Comment: can you explain how....?

Comment: That is Custom object not custom list. You have to pass ListItems.indexOf(list1), here list1 is a UserData object(Custom Object in your case).

Comment: As mentioned by Glenn passing the userData object is the right way to go, also if it is possible you could get items based on index.

Comment: @samir Read Saritha's comment

Comment: Thnx  all for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterator your array list to get your required data.
Do something like below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ListItems.size(); i++) {
        String userListName = ListItems.get(i).getListName();
        if(userListName.equals("list1")){
            //Do something here
        }else{
            //Nthng to do
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf` method is based on the argument and the item in the list being equal. Since they are not (one is a `UserData` instance and the other is a `String`), you can't use `indexOf`. Instead, you'll have to implement this logic yourself:

```
private UserData getUserDataByName(String name) {
    for (UserData item : listItems) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    // Not found, return null;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: where to store  return item ;

UserData item = getUserDataByName("list1");

String name = item.getName();

it's wotking or'not.....?

Comment: @samir yes, that should work. If you want to be extra cautious, you should check `item != null` before calling `item.getName()` though.

Answer (score 1):

In such a scenario, You can use HashMap also. Use `HashMap<String,UserData>` where String would be "list", "list1" etc.

Ex -

```
map.put("list", list);
```